# Chrome Extension's browser action with a popup that inject/delete CSS

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to ask a way to inject css or delete injected css through browse action pop up window for the chrome extension. I had try to look through few places to get ideal on how to do it but I fail to understand them.

I would like to make extension which similar to ["A browser action with a popup that changes the page color"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#a-browser-action-with-a-popup-that-changes-the-page-color) but click on the div in the popup.html to load or unload the css file that created.

This is my current work (https://github.com/Zhekoay/Self-Custom-Dark-Theme) which direct insert css using content script. Now i would like to make it able to load or unload differently instead one-time load all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome API can't remove CSS injected via manifest.json.

Inject the code just like the [demo extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/browserAction/set_page_color.zip) does, but use a `file` parameter with a name of your content script that will add or remove (if it exists) a `link` element under `document.documentElement` with an `id` equal to `chrome.runtime.id` and `href` pointing to a [web accessible](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) CSS file.

1. remove `"content_scripts"` from manifest.json
2. add `"web_accessible_resources": ["*.css"]` to manifest.json
3. add a click handler for the `div` in popup.js
4. in the click handler: `chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'content.js'});`
5. content.js:

   ```js
   (function() {
     var styleElement = document.getElementById(chrome.runtime.id);
     if (styleElement) {
       styleElement.remove();
       return;
     }
     var css = ({
       'www.youtube.com': 'app_yt_HoveredImg.css',
       'www.messenger.com': 'fb_messenger_styles.css',
       'www.google.com': 'google_styles.css',  
       'translate.google.com': 'google_styles.css',
       'apis.google.com': 'google_styles.css',
     })[location.hostname];
     if (!css) {
       return;
     }  
     styleElement = document.createElement('link');
     styleElement.id = chrome.runtime.id;
     styleElement.rel = 'stylesheet';
     styleElement.href = chrome.runtime.getURL(css);
     document.documentElement.appendChild(styleElement);
   })();
   ```

Note, in this workflow you only need [`"permissions": ["activeTab"]`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) instead of `"tabs"`: the advantage is that `activeTab` doesn't ask for permissions when the extension is installed.

Comment: It worked finally after solve few silly mistake while applying your solution. Thanks. May i ask further more about is there a way on checking or debugging for this?

Comment: Add `debugger;` in content.js and open devtools on the web page: when the script is injected the devtools debugger will activate. As for the popup, it has its own devtools: rightclick the popup and click Inspect.